# How to skip before filter in cakephp when doing ajax call

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to call a function in my application using ajax. The problem is that I don't want the function to call in the beforeFilter function of cakephp.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/users/add/'+id,
    success: function(data){

    }
});

public function add($id = NULL)
{
   echo "test";
   die;
}
```

Whenever I use the ajax call, cakephp loads the beforeFilter function.

Is there a way to bypass the beforeFilter function?

Thanks.

Comment: would you mind telling us why you would like to do this? The reason I ask is that the framework's callback methods are integral to its operation and I fear any suppression may have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CakePHP's 'Request Life-cycle callbacks'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks) are a very handy thing. They are there so that you don't have to implement such logic for every controller and are also an integrant part of [CakePHP's MVC paradigm](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html). [Look here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-structure.html) for more info on Cake's wrappers for the Models, Views and Controllers.

You can completely remove this (or any) callback via the Controller's `implementedEvents()` function but I strongly recommend not to do this.

@thaJeztah 's solution is one of the two possible.

But why do you need to bypass `beforeFilter()`? Is there a very strong thing that pushes you to do this?

You can also skip all ajax requests in the `beforeFilter()` with something like:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
     if ( !$this->request->is('ajax')) {
         //Do whatever
     }
}
```

but really do you need this? What is obstructing you there? Maybe you're using this callback method incorrectly?
Also keep in mind that hte parent controller's `beforeFilter()` will also be called if explicitly called in the child via `parent::beforeFilter()` and if there is something there the request will also go through there.

Comment: While I agree with most parts of your answer, the parent controller's beforeFilter() will *not* be called, unless you're explicitly calling it inside your overridden beforeFilter() (i.e. `parent::beforeFilter()`)

Comment: @thaJeztah you're right it will not be called unless explicitly ca;;ed.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to implement what
you're trying to do is this:

```
function beforeFilter() {
  if (in_array($this->action, array('list', 'protected', 'actions',
'here')) {
    // Do your authentication
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the current request is made via AJAX inside your beforeFilter;

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
     if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
         return;
     }

     // rest of your code
}
```

### note

This will **not** disable the beforeFilter() of *components* attached to your controller